# change cursor for autoCompleteTextView dynamically

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview

the suggestion list of my street **autoCompleteTextView** that is populate from simple cursor adapter has to be changed according the city that the user chose. I tried to use functions:

```
((SimpleCursorAdapter((AutoCompleteTextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.street)).getAdapter()).swapCursor(cursor);

((SimpleCursorAdapter((AutoCompleteTextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.street)).getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);

((SimpleCursorAdapter)((AutoCompleteTextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.street)).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and also `invalidate()` but the suggestion list still shows the result of the first cursor and not the new one.

please help me, what am I missing??

Comment: What happens if you use context in place of activity?

Comment: findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: I believe this is a separate adapter class so you have to pass the activity context from your activity to this adapter class,

otherwise debug your code and check whether you are really passing the new cursor or the 1st cursor only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was that I changed the query for the cursor adapter but didn't change the query for the `validator`. sorry for the False alarm..